# How to set the values of select html element from values retrieved by server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, struts

I have a combobox or select element of html. I want to set the values of this html element through from the values retrieved from server.

The value retreived from server array. I want to parse this array and set the value of html element.

Using struts 1.3 on server side. I have set the values on server side in an array and set its value in action form. Now without using scriptlets i want to retrieve the values and set this value to an html element using javscript.

**sample code**

```
<table width="100%">
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr>
     <td width="40%" align="right"><bean:message key="com.console.pack1"/>:</td>
        <td>
                <select name="n1">
                        <option value="0">A</option>
                        <option value="1">B</option>
                        <option value="3">C</option>
                </select>

        </td>
      </td>
</tr>
<tr id="line_second">
   <td width="40%" align="right"><bean:message key="com.console.pack2"/>:</td>
     <td>
        <select name="n2">
                        <option value="0">A</option>  // set the values of option from the array retrieved from struts action form
                        <option value="1">B</option>
                        <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>
    </td>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Values set in action Class to action form**

```
MyActionForm form = (MyActionForm) actionForm;
form.setArray(array);
```

How to set this value in html element.

Is there any workaround possible. Any ideas!!

**Remeber : **  The values of html element from server are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Idk how your getting the array I'm sure you know.

```
//set the select element to a variable

var selectEl = document.querySelector('select');

var data = [1,2,3,4,5]
for(var d of data){
 selectEl.appendChild(new Option(d, d)); //the new Option() takes two arguments 1: innerText, 2: value
}
```